# Git non-fast-forward updates were rejected Merge the remote changes

Tags: git, github

How do I resolve this issue?  I am trying to commit but I get the below error.

git push origin monty_svm_dev

```
To git@github.com:  ! [rejected]        monty_svm_dev -> monty_svm_dev
(non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to
'git@github.com:/mygit.git' To prevent you from losing history,
non-fast-forward updates were rejected Merge the remote changes before
pushing again.  See the 'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git
push --help' for details. root@li409-202:~/mypath#
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

do `git pull origin monty_svm_dev` first

What has happened is that the remote has more recent changes than your branch.

So before you can `push` your changes, you need to get and merge the changes on the remote first.

You can do this either by doing a `git checkout your_branch`, then:

`git fetch origin your_branch` and then a
`git merge your_branch`

or

```
git pull origin your_branch # fetch and merge in one operation
```

Where your branch is master, or your branch name (seems to be `monty_svm_dev` in your case I think)

Once this is done (and any conflicts resolved) you can do a `git push origin monty_svm_dev`

Comment: Or the OP might have rebased their branch.

Comment: I've heard that pull is bad because it'll merge in a way you usually don't want.  Peronally, I like to keep my history linear.  How do I accomplish that when I've run into the same error as the asker?

Comment: i tried #git pull origin devops_branch_22112016 getting error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        www/index.html
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

Comment: also tried jenkins@ip-172-31-22-20:~/workspace/directory-react-nodejs$ git fetch origin devops_branch_22112016
From github.com:HSarode-Compumatrice/directory-react-nodejs
 * branch            devops_branch_22112016 -> FETCH_HEAD
jenkins@ip-172-31-22-20:~/workspace/directory-react-nodejs$ git merge  devops_branch_22112016
Already up-to-date.
jenkins@ip-172-31-22-20:~/workspace/directory-react-nodejs$

Comment: still getting Started by user Ashish Karpe
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/directory-react-nodejs
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:HSarode-Compumatrice/directory-react-nodejs.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:HSarode-Compumatrice/directory-react-nodejs.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials

Comment: > git fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:HSarode-Compumatrice/directory-react-nodejs.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 2):

It basically because when you

> git pull

from a branch , two operations take place fetch and merge. Now if your local has some changes then git will not allow you to push it before you commit your changes.

Also this issue appears if the remote has changes which are still not pulled in local and merged, so you  need to take a pull again and then push it. Do reply if it doen't solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

This issue arises when the user forgets to issue `git push` command after `git commit` command. When using git, please always make sure the basic steps.

> In an ideal cycle while working with git, always check the following git commands were used sequentially in the following order:

```
git pull
git add
git commit
git push
```

I personally avoid majority of the issues posted about git on stack, because I always tally my git command acitivites to the above sequence.

I created an acronym to make sure I don't forget, I am hopoing the same can be useful to the reader which is:

> pacp (read it as: pack push where (p=git push, a=git add, ck=git commit, push=git push).

My way to memorise the git push, add, commit, pull is:

> get pack push (meaning: git the pack and then push).

In summary remember to "git" the pack and then "push".

Resolving the issues:
I would like to add my most used recovery git commands that are:

```
git checkout -- path/to/file/fileName.something #undo changes in file
```

> The above undoes the changes in a file...similar can be applied for multiple files using * for file name, similarly can be applied to multiple
>   directories separated by space.

```
git reset filename.txt
```

> The above removes the file from stage...after this command we can
>   safely do git commit and git will only commit those files we are in
>   stage which means the file "filname.txt" won't get committed)

```
git pull origin your_intended_branch
```

Changes are merged with the latest from your_intended_branch this basically merges the change which you committed but did not push. Once all goes fine, simply do the push:

```
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a Git pull. Then it will bring recent code changes in remote branch into your local. then you are able to push your changes.

Comment: This answer has already been given and in more detail  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12236918/1590950). If you'd like to expand and make your answer offer something that the other doesn't go ahead.